# Specific Gravity and fermentation of wine

Tags: fermentation, specific-gravity, stuck-fermentation

I thought it would be fun to make grape jelly wine. My specific gravity started at 1.104. After day five fermentation appeared to stop at 1.08. I increased the temperature, added lemon juice and yeast nutrients.Ten days after the start the SG is 1.06.
If SG is slowly going down is fermentation continuing?

Comment: Yes, if SG is decreasing, the must is fermenting.

Comment: @rob, you might as well turn this comment into an official Answer.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your gravity is going down you can feel certain that your fermentation is still continuing.

The specific gravity is in fact the only way to know, so you're monitoring your fermentation the right way.